# React Redux mapStateToProps showing old data before new data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My component data is fetched based on the route entered - `/reports/:id` i.e. `/reports/1`

the "1" following the `/reports/` is retrieved by `match.params.id` which I then make a dispatch call to the following url:

```
fetchDashData(`http://ee-etap.devops.fds.com/api/etap/v1/templates/template/report/${match.params.id}`)
```

When the user enter an invalid id, i.e. `/reports/a` - I want to redirect the user back to `/reports` which displays a landing page and error message, as such:

```
  return <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/reports',
      state: { templateId: match.params.id } }}
    />;
```

This all works fine until when the user try to visit a valid 'id', i.e. `/reports/1` right after the erroneous one - `/reports/a`, in which the user is immediately redirected back to the `/reports` page because the fetch call is asynchronous and haven't finished loading the data for `/reports/1`.

I already have isLoading state defined.. but how can I prevent this from happening?

---

**ReportsDashboard.jsx** ( `/reports/:id`)

```
 class ChartsDashboard extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchDashData, data, isLoading, hasErrored, match } = this.props;

    if ( match.params && match.params.id ) {
      fetchDashData(`http://ee-etap.devops.fds.com/api/etap/v1/templates/template/report/${match.params.id}`);
    }
  }
   render() {
    const { data, hasErrored, isLoading, classes, match } = this.props;    

    if ( isLoading ) {
      return (
        <div style={{ margin: '0 auto', textAlign: 'center' }}>
          <CircularProgress size={50} color="secondary" />
        </div>
      );
    }

    if ( data && data !== null ) {
      const { TemplateReport } = data;
      const {
        errorBarChart, historyTriggers, historyLineChart, jobs, lastBuildDonutChart, features,
      } = TemplateReport;

      if (errorBarChart.length === 0) {
        // error in data
        return <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/reports',
          state: { templateId: match.params.id } }}
        />;
      }

      const keys = [];
      errorBarChart.forEach((errorItem) => {
        Object.keys(errorItem).forEach((errorKey) => {
          if (errorKey !== 'category') {
            keys.push(errorKey);
          }
        });
      });

      if (match.params.id) {
        return (
          <div className="page-container">
            <Grid container spacing={24}>
              <Grid item xs={12} lg={4}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Error By Categories</h4>
                  <div style={{ height: '350px' }}>
                    <ResponsiveBar
                      data={errorBarChart}
                      keys={keys}
                      indexBy="category"
                      margin={{
                        top: 50,
                        right: 50,
                        bottom: 50,
                        left: 50,
                      }}
                      padding={0.1}
                      colors="paired"
                      colorBy="id"
                      axisBottom={{
                        orient: 'bottom',
                        tickSize: 5,
                        tickPadding: 5,
                        tickRotation: 0,
                        legend: 'CATEGORY',
                        legendPosition: 'middle',
                        legendOffset: 36,
                      }}
                      axisLeft={{
                        orient: 'left',
                        tickSize: 5,
                        tickPadding: 5,
                        tickRotation: 0,
                        legend: 'ERROR COUNT',
                        legendPosition: 'middle',
                        legendOffset: -40,
                      }}
                      labelSkipWidth={12}
                      labelSkipHeight={12}
                      labelTextColor="inherit:darker(1.6)"
                      animate
                      motionStiffness={90}
                      motionDamping={15}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} lg={4}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Pass Rate %</h4>
                  <div style={{ height: '350px' }}>
                    <ResponsivePie
                      colors="paired"
                      colorBy={this.pieColors}
                      margin={{
                        top: 40,
                        right: 40,
                        bottom: 40,
                        left: 40,
                      }}
                      data={lastBuildDonutChart}
                      animate
                      defs={[
                        linearGradientDef('gradientRed', [{ offset: 0, color: 'red' }, { offset: 100, color: '#ffcdd2', opacity: 0.3 }]),
                        linearGradientDef('gradientYellow', [{ offset: 0, color: 'yellow' }, { offset: 100, color: '#f7bf18a3', opacity: 0.3 }]),
                        linearGradientDef('gradientGreen', [{ offset: 0, color: '#38da3e' }, { offset: 100, color: '#38da3e', opacity: 0.3 }]),
                      ]}
                      fill={[
                        { match: { id: 'Fail' }, id: 'gradientRed' },
                        { match: { id: 'Pass' }, id: 'gradientGreen' },
                        { match: { id: 'Undefined' }, id: 'gradientYellow' },
                      ]}
                      radialLabelsSkipAngle={10}
                      radialLabelsTextXOffset={6}
                      radialLabelsTextColor="#333333"
                      radialLabelsLinkOffset={0}
                      radialLabelsLinkDiagonalLength={8}
                      radialLabelsLinkHorizontalLength={7}
                      radialLabelsLinkStrokeWidth={1}
                      radialLabelsLinkColor="inherit"
                      innerRadius={0.5}
                      padAngle={0.7}
                      cornerRadius={3}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12} lg={4}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Jobs Triggered</h4>
                  <JobsTable data={jobs} templateId={match.params.id} />
                </Paper>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Scenarios Table</h4>
                  <Tooltip title="Scenario Report">
                    <a href={`/reports/${match.params.id}/scenarioHistory`} rel="noopener noreferrer">
                      <IconButton aria-label="Scenario Report">
                        <AssignmentIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </a>
                  </Tooltip>
                  <ScenariosTable data={features} />
                </Paper>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12} lg={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Execution History</h4>
                  <div style={{ height: '400px' }}>
                    <ResponsiveLine
                      colors="paired"
                      colorBy="id"
                      margin={{
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 60,
                        left: 80,
                      }}
                      data={historyLineChart}
                      enableArea={true}
                      animate
                      yScale={{ type: 'linear', stacked: true }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </Paper>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                  <h4 className={classes.heading}>Previous Builds</h4>
                  <PreviousBuildsTable data={historyTriggers} templateId={match.params.id}/>
                </Paper>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }    

    // error in data
    return <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/reports',
                state: { templateId: match.params.id } }}
    />;

  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.reports.data,
  hasErrored: state.reports.hasErrored,
  isLoading: state.reports.isLoading,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchDashData: url => dispatch(chartDataFetch(url)),
});

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  withRouter,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  ),
)(ChartsDashboard);
```

**BrowseReport.jsx** (`/reports/`)

```
class BrowseReports extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchVal: '',
      errorMsg: '',
    }

    this.onSearchChange = this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
    this.goToTemplateReport = this.goToTemplateReport.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.location && this.props.location.state && this.props.location.state.templateId) {
      this.state.errorMsg = `Template Name "${this.props.location.state.templateId}" does not exist, please try again`;
      this.props.history.replace('/reports', null);
    }
  }

  onSearchChange(val) {
    this.setState({ searchVal: val });
  }

  goToTemplateReport(val) {
    this.props.history.push(`/reports/${val}`);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, location } = this.props;
    const { searchVal, errorMsg } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="page-container" style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={8}>

          {/* dashData Error */}

            <h4 className={classes.errorMsg}>
              {/* ERROR MESSAGE HERE  */}
              {errorMsg}
            </h4>
            <SearchBar
              value={this.state.searchVal}
              placeholder='Search for Template Name'
              onChange={(value) => this.onSearchChange(value)}
              onRequestSearch={(value) => this.goToTemplateReport(value)}
              style={{
                margin: '0 auto',
              }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <CompletedJobsTable></CompletedJobsTable>
              </Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <ActiveJobsTable></ActiveJobsTable>
              </Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  withStyles(styles),
  withRouter
)(BrowseReports);
```

**actions.jsx**

```
export const chartDataHasErrored = hasErrored => ({
  type: CHARTS_DATA_HAS_ERRORED,
  payload: { hasErrored },
});

export const chartDataIsLoading = isLoading => ({
  type: CHARTS_DATA_IS_LOADING,
  payload: { isLoading },
});

export const chartDataFetchSuccess = data => ({
  type: CHARTS_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  payload: { data },
});

export const chartDataFetch = url => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(chartDataIsLoading(true));
  fetch(url, { mode: 'cors' })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error(response.statusText);
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((items) => {
      dispatch(chartDataFetchSuccess(items));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(chartDataHasErrored(error));
    });
};
```

**reducers.jsx**

```
import { CHARTS_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS, CHARTS_DATA_IS_LOADING, CHARTS_DATA_HAS_ERRORED } from '../../../store/actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hasErrored: null,
  isLoading: true,
  data: {},
}

const reportsDashboardReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case CHARTS_DATA_HAS_ERRORED:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasErrored: action.payload.hasErrored,
        isLoading: false,
      };

    case CHARTS_DATA_IS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: action.payload.isLoading,
        hasErrored: null,
      };

    case CHARTS_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        data: action.payload.data,
      };    

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reportsDashboardReducer;
```

Comment: this.state.errorMsg = 'Template .....` - never change state this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save templateId in the global state (set it when data loaded). In component data need to be shown only if templateId from the path equal to the templateId from the global state.

Comment: The issue right now is the old data stay there while I wait for the new fetch to complete, which will cause the first render to be inaccurate and gets me redirected when I really want to remain on the page till it reload with the new correct data.

Comment: Clearing it in componentDidMount doesn’t work. Render happens before componentDidMount.